# GCP Cloud Run 503 Error: Service unavailable for asp.net website

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to deploy the asp.net website in cloud run but am stuck with this error - "**The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error**. **(Service Unavailable 503**)"

This is https & http docker files. one of many such services.

[image]

[image]

for http-5176 -- http URL of cloud run is not registered in the azureAD app - I'm getting can't redirect error when I access the cloud run URL which is expected that is fine.

but for https-7176 -- https URL of cloud run which is registered in azureAD is immediately throwing Service Unavailable 503, not sure whether it is redirected to auth or not.

Thing is, when I try these two container images locally in docker desktop it is working fine - https://localhost:PORT redirects to authentication page and website is loaded as expected with some other api call errors. But when I deploy the same in cloud run -- Service Unavailable 503
Cloud run config

- 2 CPU limit
- 512MB Memory limit
- 1 Concurrency
- 500sec request timeout

Tried some troubleshooting

- Concurrency is at low
- No VPC access connector is used for now.
- No errors on memory exceeding in logs

Expecting - to authenticate and load webpage knowing that there are few api error in that to work on later.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this? And how to reslove this?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: I'm unclear of your configuration (and how Azure AD needs to be configured) but, while Cloud Run allows you to run containers on any port (e.g. 5176|7176) **as long as** you configure the port when you `gcloud run deploy ... --port=5176 ...` (or equivalent), the Cloud Run service that's deployed will only listen on 443. Could that be your issue?

Comment: What do the Cloud Run logs show? Your container (app) has a problem. 5xx errors mean something is wrong with your app/service, the request, available containers, etc. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, In logs - service is up(listening on the specified port) and running. when I trigger the URL. In logs, I get this ERROR - **The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or the connection to the instance had an error. (Service Unavailable 503)**.

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin, when i trigger https://localhost:PORT it is redirecting to next step (Authentication - azure app configured in code). i got this error which is expected because https://localhost:PORT URL is not listed in azure app but i registered cloud run URL in azure app for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cloud run redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS. after a long trial and error, with my application team. In the code, they added a redirection from HTTP to HTTPS and I'm running my cloud-run service in the HTTP port. Now it is working fine.